# How to have simultaneous setLocation and setText in JLabel?

Tags: java, jlabel, sleep, settext

In the try block of my code either of setText() or setLocation() are working well separately as explained below:

Following code move the label in right way (each time 50 pxl) according to given sleep:

```
                ......... 
                label.setLocation((label.getLocationOnScreen().x+50),0);
                Thread.sleep(time[i]); 
                ...............
```

Following  code set the text properly ("Name 1", "Name 2", etc.) according to given sleep:

```
                ...................                                     
                label.setText(name[i]); 
                Thread.sleep(time[i]); 
                ....................
```

Following  code set the text properly ("Name 1", "Name 2", etc.) according to given sleep but does not move the JLabel:

```
                ....................
                label.setText(name[i]); 
                label.setLocation((label.getLocationOnScreen().x+50),0);
                Thread.sleep(time[i]); 
                ....................
```

I need both of them. In other words in first movement it should show "Name 1", in the 2nd movement "Name 2" and so on.

I am new comer to java and programming. So kindly help me to get  the required output. Thanks in anticipation.

My complete code is as below:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

class Move {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Journey");
    static int x=0;


public Move() {
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(800,600);
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        frame.add(label); 
        label.setLocation(0, 0); 
        frame.setVisible(true);

    doAll();
}

    void doAll(){ 
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
            try{
                String[] name={"Name 1","Name 2","Name 3","Name 4","Name 5","Name 6","Name 7","Name 8","Name 9","Name 10"};
                int time []={2000,1000,2000,1000,2000,1000,2000,1000,2000,1000};

                for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
                label.setText(name[i]); 
                label.setLocation((label.getLocationOnScreen().x+50),0);
                Thread.sleep(time[i]);  

                } 
            }catch(Exception ae){

        }
    }
});

t.start();
}

public static void main(String[]args){
    new Move();  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than trying to move a Swing component, you can draw an image on a JPanel and move the image.

Here's the GUI I created.

[image: Image Move GUI]

1. You must start a Swing application with a call to the SwingUtilities invokeLater method.  This method puts the creation and usage of all the Swing components on the [Event Dispatch thread (EDT)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).
2. Whenever you try to coordinate 2 or more arrays, you should consider creating a model class.  I created the Leg class to hold the name and the delay.  That way, I only had to create the one List in the Journey class.
3. I created a DrawingPanel from a JPanel.  Always create your GUI on a JPanel.  Never create your GUI directly on a JFrame.
4. Run your animation in a separate Runnable, Thread, or Swing Timer.  The GUI runs on its own thread, and your animation code has to run in a different thread, or you block the GUI from updating.
5. Since the animation is running in a separate thread, the setting of the Leg in the drawing panel is enclosed in a SwingUtilities invokeLater method.  This ensures that the drawing happens on the Event Dispatch thread (EDT).
6. When I created the JFrame, I added a WindowListener to the JFrame.  That's so I could detect the window closing, and stop the animation before I exited the program.

Here's the code.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.font.FontRenderContext;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ImageMove implements Runnable {

    private JFrame frame;

    private JourneyRunnable journeyRunnable;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new ImageMove());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        frame = new JFrame("Image Move");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent event) {
                exitProcedure();
            }
        });

        DrawingPanel drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel();
        frame.add(drawingPanel);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        journeyRunnable = new JourneyRunnable(drawingPanel, new Journey());
        new Thread(journeyRunnable).start();
    }

    public void exitProcedure() {
        journeyRunnable.setRunning(false);
        frame.dispose();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -8498462824787395933L;

        private int xPos, yPos, width, height;

        private Leg leg;

        public DrawingPanel() {
            this.width = 100;
            this.height = 50;
            this.xPos = 0;
            this.yPos = (200 - height) / 2;
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 200));
        }

        public void setLeg(Leg leg) {
            this.leg = leg;
            this.xPos += 10;
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

            g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
            g.fillRect(xPos, yPos, width, height);

            if (leg != null) {
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                centerString(g, new Rectangle(xPos, yPos, width, height),
                        leg.getName(), g.getFont());
            }
        }

        /**
         * This method centers a <code>String</code> in a bounding
         * <code>Rectangle</code>.
         * 
         * @param g
         *            - The <code>Graphics</code> instance.
         * @param r
         *            - The bounding <code>Rectangle</code>.
         * @param s
         *            - The <code>String</code> to center in the bounding
         *            rectangle.
         * @param font
         *            - The display font of the <code>String</code>
         * 
         * @see java.awt.Graphics
         * @see java.awt.Rectangle
         * @see java.lang.String
         */
        public void centerString(Graphics g, Rectangle r, String s, Font font) {
            FontRenderContext frc = new FontRenderContext(null, true, true);

            Rectangle2D r2D = font.getStringBounds(s, frc);
            int rWidth = (int) Math.round(r2D.getWidth());
            int rHeight = (int) Math.round(r2D.getHeight());
            int rX = (int) Math.round(r2D.getX());
            int rY = (int) Math.round(r2D.getY());

            int a = (r.width / 2) - (rWidth / 2) - rX;
            int b = (r.height / 2) - (rHeight / 2) - rY;

            g.setFont(font);
            g.drawString(s, r.x + a, r.y + b);
        }
    }

    public class JourneyRunnable implements Runnable {

        private boolean running;

        private DrawingPanel drawingPanel;

        private Journey journey;

        public JourneyRunnable(DrawingPanel drawingPanel, Journey journey) {
            this.drawingPanel = drawingPanel;
            this.journey = journey;
            this.running = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (running) {
                Leg leg = journey.getLeg();
                setLeg(leg);
                sleep(leg);
            }
        }

        public void setLeg(final Leg leg) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    drawingPanel.setLeg(leg);
                }
            });
        }

        private void sleep(Leg leg) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(leg.getDelay());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            }
        }

        public void setRunning(boolean running) {
            this.running = running;
        }

    }

    public class Journey {

        private int index;
        private List<Leg> legs;

        public Journey() {
            this.legs = new ArrayList<>();

            this.legs.add(new Leg("Name 1", 2000L));
            this.legs.add(new Leg("Name 2", 1000L));
            this.legs.add(new Leg("Name 3", 2000L));
            this.legs.add(new Leg("Name 4", 1000L));
            this.legs.add(new Leg("Name 5", 2000L));
            this.legs.add(new Leg("Name 6", 1000L));
            this.legs.add(new Leg("Name 7", 2000L));
            this.legs.add(new Leg("Name 8", 1000L));
            this.legs.add(new Leg("Name 9", 2000L));
            this.legs.add(new Leg("Name 10", 1000L));

            this.index = 0;
        }

        public Leg getLeg() {
            Leg leg = legs.get(index);
            index = ++index % legs.size();
            return leg;
        }
    }

    public class Leg {
        private final String name;
        private final long delay;

        public Leg(String name, long delay) {
            this.name = name;
            this.delay = delay;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public long getDelay() {
            return delay;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Your answer worked well and it is also densely educative.

Answer (score 0):

The problem looks like the LayoutManager of the frame is setting the location of the label for you.

What you need to do is set the layout to null:

```
 frame.setLayout(null);
```

This will make it so the frame doesn't try to layout the components by itself.

then you can do

```
label.setLocation((label.getLocationOnScreen().x+50),0);
```

However, having no layout isn't ideal, but `GridLayout` isn't really great for what you want, either.

**Reason**: `GridLayout` will always sort the components in the order you write "`container.add(component)`" statements. You can't put a component at a specific place, other than by inserting dummy components for all the places before.

You might want to try `GridBagLayout`.. In `GridBagLayout`, all you've to do on key event is to update the location of your dynamic panel and it shall be displayed on the top of the fixed panel at that location.